# TypeORM Database Lock: Please explain how to use database lock in TypeORM using setLock() function

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I want to implement database row wise lock in PostgreSQL with Nestjs and TypeORM.
Could you please any one let me know how to implement it in correct way. I tried with the following code but not sure whether it is locking the particular row.

```
async testFun(): Promise<any> {
        const user = await this.userRepo
                    .createQueryBuilder("user")
                    .useTransaction(true)
                    .setLock("pessimistic_write")
                    .where("id = :id", { id: 2 })
                    .getOne()

        const updateResult: any = await this.userRepo.createQueryBuilder('test')
                                .update()
                                .set({ fullname: "frm3000" })
                                .where("id = :id", { id: 2 })
                                .execute();
        
        return updateResult;
    }
```

Query generated by TypeORM is,

```
query: START TRANSACTION
query: SELECT * FROM "users" "user" WHERE id = $1 FOR UPDATE -- PARAMETERS: [2]      
query: COMMIT
query: UPDATE "users" SET "fullname" = $1 WHERE "id" = $2 -- PARAMETERS: ["from3000",2]
```

Here commit done before update query, so doubted whether the row locked or not.

Also I want to test it in my local host, with two different Ports localhost:3000 and localhost:3001. Hence I added same controller and service code in another app with port 3001 with delay,

```
async testFun(): Promise<any> {
        const user = await this.userRepo
                    .createQueryBuilder("user")
                    .useTransaction(true)
                    .setLock("pessimistic_write")
                    .where("id = :id", { id: 2 })
                    .getOne()
        

        function sleep(ms) {
            return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
        }
        await sleep(20000);

        const updateResult: any = await this.userRepo.createQueryBuilder('test')
                                .update()
                                .set({ fullname: "frm3001" })
                                .where("id = :id", { id: 2 })
                                .execute();
        
        return updateResult;
    }
```

Please let me know is this approach correct or suggest better way if any.
Also the testing approach too not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Since you are running `query` without starting a `transaction` on `TypeORM`. All the individual `queries` are considered as a separate `transaction` on `database`.

To run a set of `queries` in a `single transaction` you have to `Demarcate transaction` at application level.
One of the ways to set `transaction` demarcation with `TypeORM` is by using [QueryRunner](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/query-runner).

Do the following steps:

```
const queryRunner = getConnection().createQueryRunner();
  
try {
    await queryRunner.connect();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();
    const user = await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(User)
                    .createQueryBuilder("user")
                    .useTransaction(true)
                    .setLock("pessimistic_write")
                    .where("id = :id", { id: 2 })
                    .getOne()
    function sleep(ms) {
         return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
    await sleep(20000);

    const updateResult: any = await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(User)
                                .createQueryBuilder('test')
                                .update()
                                .set({ fullname: "frm3001" })
                                .where("id = :id", { id: 2 })
                                .execute();
    await queryRunner.commitTransaction();    
    return updateResult;
} catch(e) {
    await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
} finally {
    await queryRunner.release();
}
```

> NOTE: Never forget to release the queryRunner, otherwise your db connections will be used up.

Hope this helps.